# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x60) in coredata saving

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Im trying to save the objects to core data and im getting this "Zombie" error randomly. Any insights would be helpful

[image]

However I guess there could be something wrong here too.
[image]

Comment: you're using mainContext in background thread.
to fix it, ensure that fetchData is called on mainQueue

Comment: I dont use background but i use async. but why would that be an issue

Comment: I'm not sure about your code, but the thread-15 isn't main thread.
you can add `assert(Thread.isMainThread)` to check, before return statement